# how can I check for Bluetooth's Serial Number on Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift5, serial-number

I am using SwiftifyBluetooth on Cocoapods but... I did use discoverServices but it only showed as its CBService's value... but I can't seem to know how to convert from its value to string... I checked on how SwiftifyBluetooth and Core Bluetooth work and hit a dead end from myself...

here is the code:

```
peri[0].discoverServices(withUUIDs: nil, completion: {
                result in
                switch result{
                    
                case .success(let services):
                    print(services)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    break
                }
            })
```

and this was the outputted printed in the services
EDIT:
[<CBService: 0x283f14ac0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1804>, <CBService: 0x283f14700, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Battery>, <CBService: 0x283f15480, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>, <CBService: 0x283f15840, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455>]

I was just checking if this is possible to convert the the CBServices value from that datatype to string

Comment: Try `service.uuid.uuidString` .

Comment: @Yonat it doesn't have the scope for that...

Comment: What do you mean? What happens if you print `services.first?.uuid.uuidString`?

Comment: it printed as nil

Comment: Is `services` an array? Or a single `CBService`? Each `CBService` has a `uuid`, and the `uuid.uuidString` is the string ID for that service.

Comment: @Yonat it is an array with "[<CBService: , isPrimary = ,  UUID = >]" in 3 indexes IDK if this is NSDictionary. and its not

Comment: So check where the nil is coming from: is `services.first` nil? If not, is `services.first?.uuid` nil? If it is, it may be a problem with SwiftyBluetooth. Not sure why you would need it over using CoreBluetooth directly.

Comment: @Yonat both of them arent printing any nil anymore its showing like this:

for `services.first` its printed as this: Optional(<CBService: 0x280c44c40, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 1804>)
and for `services.first?.uuid` is this : 1804. its just me being a PICNIC (Problem In Chair Not In Computer)

Comment: Also SwiftyBluetooth is just using the same changes as CBCentralManager and CBPeripherals

also also they was a Code for the machine but it was already Deprecated

Comment: So `services.first?.uuid` is not nil but `services.first?.uuid.uuidString` is nil? This is really weird. I don't know how it's possible.

Comment: @Yonat isnt `services.first?.uuid.uuidString` is just converts uuid to string

Comment: Yes, that's the way to get the string representation of the uuid.

Comment: @Yonat it printed the same as `services.first?.uuid.uuidString` printed as 1804

Comment: So it does work, great!

Comment: then what should I do next??? @Yonat

Comment: Use the `services.first?.uuid.uuidString`, wasn't that what you asked about?

Comment: I did that already and there will be a new post for the CBCharacteristics just a sec @Yonat also that's just bluetooth services

Answer (score 0):

So I did found a way after I to discover the characteristics put the "180A" in the service UUID to get the Device info as said to the cheat sheet I found about Bluetooth BLE but now my concern why is it showing values as "(null)"

Code after Discovering Services and the Characteristics

```
periphers[indexing].discoverServices(completion: {
            result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let service):
                print(service)
                break
            case .failure(_):
                break
                }
        })
        
        periphers[indexing].discoverCharacteristics(ofServiceWithUUID: "180A", completion: {
            result in
            switch result{
                case .success(let service):
                    print(service)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    break
            }
        })
```

output:
[Output of Characteristics value being null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94p4q.png)